# 3 Points, 1 angle - Java (2D)

Tags: java, geometry, 2d, angle

I have read how to calculate the triangle with 3 points and its angles. The problem is, I have tried different approaches and still get strange results. That can only mean I am doing something simple terribly wrong. But I am too much into my programming to see it; maybe anyone of you can help me?

I have 3 points: u, v and w

> u---------------v

w is under u and v. I now want to get the angle in ° at w, which spans the triangle to u and v.

The coordinates are defined by u(ux,uy) v(vx,vy) w(wx,wy)

```
double dn = 
    Math.sqrt(Math.pow(ux-wx, 2)+Math.pow(uy-wy, 2))
        * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(vx-wx, 2)+Math.pow(vy-wy, 2));
            
double beta = Math.acos(((ux-wx)*(vx-wx)+(uy-wy)*(vy-wy))/(dn));
```

`beta` is always less than 3.5, so I can't really figure out what I did wrong. Or did I understand the formula wrong? All variables are double, so that can be excluded I think.

I used:

[image: this one]
<sub>(source: [matheplanet.com](http://fed.matheplanet.com/mprender.php?stringid=14589638))</sub>
.

Comment: http://s27.postimg.org/f46zaw23n/UVW.jpg it is o.O

Comment: thx for unnecessary edit ...

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but i think acos will gave you angle in radians, so you should get answer in range (0,+PI), have try pass yor result to Math.toDegrees() function

Comment: Thank you, I think thats the correct answer. I was so into it that I didnt notice.